# Emirates Business Class Overhead Bin

Tags: business-travel, emirates

On the 22nd of July, I will be traveling on Emirates Business Class. Usually, when I travel, I only carry with me my small backpack (Which weighs less than 4kg.) When I travel with different airlines, they allow me to place it either in front or under my seat. The flight attendants tell me it's better to be placed either in front or under the seat. I was wondering; can I do the same thing with Emirates?

Comment: Have you asked Emirates?

Comment: I do not know about the specific of emirates or the equipment of your flight - but in business class there is usually no "under the seat". there might be a small compartment in front. you always have a larger overhead space ( less seats on same area). I would say don't worry - you will find the right place for your stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If it fits, there's a little area next to your seat/by your feet in front.  There's a lot of space.

Worst case, they'll likely offer to fetch it for you if you need it during flight.  It's less about the weight and more the size.

Source: Flew Emirates business on two legs last year and in first once this year, kept bag by feet.